# How can I obtain password hash from ParseUser?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am currently in the process of migrating all user accounts of my parse-server backend to a 3rd-party SSO provider. The provider allows me to import users with pre-hashed passwords, allowing me to do the transition without needing the users to sign-in to finish the migration process.

I have been having issues trying to obtain the hashed password from the ParseUser object. I can see it in the MongoDB (the *_hashed_password* field), however I have been unable to extract the password field from the queried object.

I obtain the ParseUser object via the following query (simplified, removed async/await)

```js
const query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
query.find({useMasterKey: true}).then(users => {
  users.forEach(user => {
    // obtain password here + do migration
  })
});
```

I have attempted to get the password via

```js
user.getPassword() 
user.get("password") 
user.get("_hashed_password")
query.select(["_hashed_password", "password"]).find({useMasterKey: true}).then(...)
```

The getPassword() function does not exist, but I wanted to try it anyway. the get("password") and get("_hashed_password) returns undefined.
The query.select(...) returns the entire user (except the password), even though I thought it would return either the password or an empty object.

My question is: How can I programatically get the hashed password of a user on the parse platform?

Currently for debugging purposes I am developing this migration as a cloud function. Once I have it working I was planning to move it as a job. I believe this should have no effect on the way the code works, but am leaving this note here just in case anyway.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The password hash is protected by default and can't be retrieved via API using queries. You should be able to retrieve via aggregate though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Davi Macêdo, I figured it out.

One has to use aggregate query, however the field _hashed_password gets filtered out by Parse even in aggregate queries, so we need to compute additional field based on the _hashed_password. The following code works:

```js
new Parse.Query(Parse.User).aggregate({
  "project": {
    "myPassword": "$_hashed_password"
  }
})
```

Comment: That's bad practise to get user password hash. should avoid fetch password hash for security reasons.

Comment: I dont even see `_hashed_password` in mongo and when i do this aggregate query all i see is objectId